# Error with checking JDBC lookup using jUnit tests with Maven project in Netbeans

Tags: java, unit-testing, jakarta-ee, maven, junit

I'm trying to create a test for a file that's using a jdbc resource. Regular tests work fine throughout the project, except for when I'm trying to test something that is using an entity manager. I think I'm missing something simple here and would appreciate any help.

Here's the error.

```
Feb 27, 2012 3:04:44 PM com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle deploy
SEVERE: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jdbc/foundation' in SerialContext[myEnv={com.sun.enterprise.connectors.jndisuffix=__pm, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: foundation not found]
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jdbc/foundation' in SerialContext[myEnv={com.sun.enterprise.connectors.jndisuffix=__pm, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: foundation not found]
```

Here's some of the troubleshooting steps I've taken:

- Added the glassfish extras to the maven POM
- I have placed the persistence file in both the /main/resources and /test/resources folders.
- I have tried adding properties to the context object in the @BeforeClass method in the DonationsFacadeTest file along with about a million other configurations similar to the one below.

Environment Info:

- Using Netbeans 7.0.1
- Maven Project
- Glassfish 3.1

DonationsFacade.java - This class is using a facade pattern to provide indirect access to JPA entities.

```
@Stateless
public class DonationsFacade extends AbstractFacade<Donations> {
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "FoundationPU")
private EntityManager em;

protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}

public DonationsFacade() {
    super(Donations.class);
}

public boolean setPaid(int id, String transId)
{
    try{
        Donations don = em.find(Donations.class, id);
        don.setStatus("Paid");
        don.setConfirmationnumber(transId);
        em.persist(don);
        em.flush(); 
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Test File - Just trying to write a simple test to to verify the data.

```
public class DonationsFacadeTest {

@Test
public void testSetPaid() throws Exception {
    int id = 1;
    String transId = "123";
    EJBContainer ejbC = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer();
    Context ctx = ejbC.getContext();      
    DonationsFacade instance = (DonationsFacade)ctx.lookup("java:global/classes/DonationsFacade");
    boolean expResult = false;
    boolean result = instance.setPaid(id, transId);
    assertEquals(expResult, result);
    ejbC.close();
}
}
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"...>
  <persistence-unit name="FoundationPU" transaction-type="JTA">
   <jta-data-source>jdbc/foundation</jta-data-source>
   <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

glassfish-resources.xml

```
<resources>
<jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jdbc/foundation" object-type="user"   pool-name="mysql_foundation_rootPool">
<description/>
</jdbc-resource>
<jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" 
              associate-with-thread="false" 
              connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" 
              connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" 
              connection-leak-reclaim="false" 
              connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" 
              connection-validation-method="table" 
              datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" 
              fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" 
              is-connection-validation-required="false" 
              is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" 
              lazy-connection-association="false" 
              lazy-connection-enlistment="false" 
              match-connections="false" 
              max-connection-usage-count="0" 
              max-pool-size="32" 
              max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" 
              name="connectionPool" 
              non-transactional-connections="false" 
              ping="false" 
              pool-resize-quantity="2" 
              pooling="true" 
              res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
              statement-cache-size="0" 
              statement-leak-reclaim="false" 
              statement-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" 
              statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" 
              steady-pool-size="8" 
              validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" 
              wrap-jdbc-objects="true">
<property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/foundation"/>
<property name="User" value="root"/>
<property name="Password" value="thepassword"/>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
</resources>
```

Again, thanks for the help, very much appreciated.

Comment: Is Glassfish running when you execute the test?  What is the JNDI provider?

Comment: Yes, glassfish is running. I think it's just the typical MySQL jdbc provider.

Comment: No, the JNDI naming service is part of Glassfish.  How do you tell an application that's not running inside of Glassfish, like your unit test, to use the Glassfish JNDI naming service?

Comment: Apparently, I don't. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Better get a shovel and start digging.  Or learn to use Spring.

Comment: Any thoughts on how I can start digging? Embedded Glassfish?

Comment: Look at docs on how to use JNDI naming services outside of the Java EE app server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer here. I basically injected a entitymanager into the class. Hopefully this is helpful to someone who is trying to do this same thing.

```
public class DonationsFacadeTest {


private EntityManager em; 
private EntityTransaction tx; 
DonationsFacade donations;

public DonationsFacadeTest() {
}

@Before
public void setUpClass() throws Exception {

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Foundation2");
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
    tx = em.getTransaction(); 
    this.donations = new DonationsFacade(); 
    this.donations.em = em;
}

/**
 * Test of setPaid method, of class DonationsFacade.
 */
@Test
public void testSetPaid() throws Exception {

    int id = 1;
    String transId = "123";

    boolean expResult = false;
    boolean result = donations.setPaid(id, transId);
    assertEquals(expResult, result);

}
}
```

Modified the persistence.xml file appropriately.

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" ... >
<persistence-unit name="Foundation2" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>org.scmc.foundation.session.DonationsFacadeTest</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
       <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"   value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
       <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/foundation"/>
       <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
       <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

And finally added the appropriate driver to the POM file.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.18</version>
    </dependency>
```